# UICollectionView change layout - change cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView which uses `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`. I've added a method which changes the layout when tapping a cell `setCollectionViewLayout`.

All the cells have a text label with text and I would like to empty all the text labels on every cell when changing the layout. What's the best way to accomplish that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine the simplest way is just to call `reloadData` on your collection view at the same time that you change the layout (and have a conditional in your `cellForItem` data source method that empties the text labels upon each layout change).

Alternatively, you could have your `UICollectionViewCells` keep track of the layout they're currently displayed in, and adjust their views accordingly.

Comment: Thanks man. I used [[[self collectionView] collectionViewLayout] isKindOfClass:[CircleLayout class]] which worked great. Don't know if that's the best way to do it. The only problem now is that the animation between layouts doesn't really work since I'm calling reloadData.

Comment: The second approach that I suggested might work better and retain the animations between layouts - only downside is it's going to be a little harder to implement. You might want to try triggering a `NSNotification` when your layout changes, and having your cells listen out for it. That way you'll never have to reload them, and the animation should remain.

Comment: Yes, that might be the way to go. Thanks. On a side note, I'm trying to make my collectionview work similar to the photos app on the iPad. Do you think that apple used one collectionview and only changed the layouts? Maybe I should open a second question for that.